# Draw a path for a robot to follow

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a omni-directional robot to follow a user input path. My first idea was to override the global path planner. After reading about it for a few days I think that it might work but it there is probably a better way. The navigation stack seems to be more from getting from A to B, not "hit all this waypoints". Meaning I would have to put every point(or some interval of the points) into the  `makeplan` function of the global planner. But this seems ineffective and cause the robot to shake.
It seems like there should be an easier way. As anybody done this before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223867/draw-a-path-for-a-robot-to-follow/) by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Write a plugin for the global planner where you create the global plan the way you want it. You could input it by subscribing to a topic, e.g.

Thus, you would make use of the rest of move_base but have full flexibility.
However, you would need to stick the global planner interface.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-16**:
hello, assuming you are talking about this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS)

How would I define a sine/circular paths? or any other paths defined by a mathematical function